# Are questions about widgets used with an Arduino on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

This topic has been discussed previously but not seemingly clearly resolved. (ref. [Are questions that are only related to Arduino by the parts used on topic?](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200/are-questions-that-are-only-related-to-arduino-by-the-parts-used-on-topic)).

Recently (early 2022) some community members have been implementing a strict policy that seems to me to have low utility, and to be somewhat harsh (ref. [Looking for vibration sensor](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/88969/looking-for-vibration-sensor), [Continuous servo motor](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/88978/continuous-servo-motor)).

I would argue that questions about using Arduino MCU's **often** relate to the parts selected and interfaced. That's why the community has tags to identify these topics. Some of the tag info wiki's specifically encourage such questions. (e.g., [Sensors tag](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/tags/sensors/info), "*Use this tag for questions about selecting, connecting, using, and debugging sensors.*") If the **spirit** of the question is about using the arduino ecosystem, then I think the community should start the conversation in as friendly and as tolerant a way as possible in the spirit of exploring what might be a useful question.

Currently the [on-topic help](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says (regarding General Electronics being off-topic) that, "***If knowledge of Arduino would improve a question, it's on topic.***". If an OP is asking about connecting a widget to an Arduino board then while they might not know if the issues are specific to Arduino, I believe they are hoping that we as a community might. Similarly, if a widget might possibly be connected to something other than an Arduino that shouldn't automatically make it off-topic.

Is the community able to:

1. agree a more objective policy
2. if so update the help page
3. follow a more tolerant implementation strategy?

My suggestions regarding implementation are:

- Leave a couple of days before closing doubtful questions of this type
- If the question generates useful on-topic comments or answers, then it should be deemed on-topic
- If there is a history of similar questions and answers being on-topic, then the question should be deemed on-topic (but may possibly be a duplicate)
- That the community should focus on the OP *intent* more than the letter of the "on-topic" law

Comment: I've seen literally most of the question posted here downvoted or closed, which doesn't help anyone. It's probably the "problem of small authority" in an over-zealous mod, but perhaps the acceptability criteria need loosened. Or whomever is just being a jerk needs to chill a bit...

Answer (score 1):

What is on topic on Arduino SE is in Help Center in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Some type of questions, even on-topic, is not suitable for Q&A format. There is Help Center article [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Some questions are in the gray zone for on-topic and/or Q&A format. Then it is on community members with close vote privilege to decide about the question with close votes.

On-topicness should not be discussed in comments under the question. The right place is the Meta. If you see such a comment, flag it as "no longer needed".

On-topicness of the question about the vibration sensor linked in question, depends on the solution. I for example don't know if there is a couple of established ways to measure vibration with Arduino or the answer is generic and opinion based.

I don't see a reason to change the Help pages about scope of Arduino SE.

Your suggestions are valid but it is on the community members to implement them. As a moderator I only close questions which are clearly off topic or miss important details and could attract low quality answers (Then I follow the question to reopen after it is completed).

Comment: Keep up the great work you are doing here on Arduino SE :)